# How to Cascade Lookup columns in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, jquery, spservices

I have two lists called "**Project Managers**" and "**Projects**".

In **ProjectManagers** list I have added some names in Title column. 
In **Projects** list I have created a column(Projectmanagernames) which is Lookup column related to **Project managers** list.

My requirement is when I select ProjectManagersname in the first dropdown, in the second dropdown projects has to come which are related to selected project manager name.

I have tried SPservices also but I'm unable to achieve this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Try this....http://www.markrackley.net/2014/05/20/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint-office-365-using-rest/

Answer (score 0):

You can by using SPServices, for full tutorial please visit http://sharepointkids.blogspot.in/2014/04/two-level-cascading-drop-down-in.html

Comment: Gowtham, link only answers are frowned upon here because it's very common that the link will become inactive in the future rendering your post worthless for those who come here looking for an answer in the future. Please paraphrase any applicable information from the blog post.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer